# How to break a row into several rows when going to smaller screens in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
   <div class="row second-row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
      </div>
    </div>
```

When we have a big screen, al the images show side by side on the same row, and when I go to a smaller screen they stack one on top of the other. 
How can I make a break between each image? I need it to have a white space like each image was on a different row.
I tried adding `<br>` that were only visible with xs or sm but it didn't work. Is this possible in a simple way, or should I add paddings on a media query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it works.

```
<div class="row second-row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 visible-xs">
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 visible-xs">
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 visible-xs">
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
   .col-class-here {
      margin-top: 15px;
   }
}
```

Why would there be a problem with doing this? Pretty much what you suggested yourself. This IS a simple way.

Comment: I just wondered if there was a way of Bootstrap knowing that it was originally one row but now it is several rows, so it needs a break. Thank you so much!

Comment: No, bootstrap won't do that automatically. Perhaps you shouldn't even think of the .row class as a row because all the .row class does is add some margin on the left and the right.